# Copying values from TABLEA to TABLEB with use of Cursor

Tags: sql, sybase

I'd like to copy values from TableA to TableB using cursor but getting troubles all the time. Here is my code:

```
DROP TABLE #Firmy
DROP TABLE #Faktury
CREATE TABLE #Firmy (
                idfirmy VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Firmy VALUES ('00001936')
INSERT INTO #Firmy VALUES ('00002059')
CREATE TABLE #Faktury (
                idfirmy VARCHAR(255)--,
                --idfaktury VARCHAR(255)
)
DECLARE fakturyc CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #Firmy 
FOR loop1 AS fakturyc
DO 
    INSERT INTO #Faktury VALUES fakturyc 
END FOR
```

Getting "Syntax error near loop1". Can someone help me with solving this? Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you want to use a (slow) cursor solution for that? A simple `insert into #Faktury (idfirmy) select idfirmy from #Firmy` will be **much** more efficient

Comment: But I just want to learn how to get values from cursor. I know it's much slower, but I want to select value from cursor. Please, tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually T-sql: but may work in sybase as well

```
DROP TABLE #Firmy
DROP TABLE #Faktury
CREATE TABLE #Firmy (
                idfirmy VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Firmy VALUES ('00001936')
INSERT INTO #Firmy VALUES ('00002059')
CREATE TABLE #Faktury (
                idfirmy VARCHAR(255)--,
                --idfaktury VARCHAR(255)
)

declare @col1 varchar(10)
declare copy cursor for
select idfirmy from #Firmy -- select top 1 * from #Firmy

open copy 
fetch next from copy into @col1

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
insert into #Faktury(idfirmy) values(@col1)
fetch next from copy into @col1
end
close copy
deallocate copy

select * from #Faktury
select * from #Firmy
```

The `simplified Query` will be

```
insert into #Faktury
select * from #Firmy
```

Comment: Actually I want to do something like this: 

`DECLARE @Firma 
FOR namesx AS curs CURSOR FOR SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dba.Firmy AS f
DO
    FETCH curs INTO @Firma
END FOR;
SELECT @Firma`

Comment: you could modify select as you need ! pls see edit ;)